# sim card with disabled TS11 (Tele Service: Telephony) drains battery

Tags: android

I have a sim card with disabled TS11 (Tele Service: Telephony), im using this card only for data connection. My question is: it is possible to disalble TS11 service on android? Because when this sim card is in use, my phone thinks that there is no service and trying to find network wchich causes battery drain. Is there any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known problem with data-only SIM cards. To fix this, you'll need a rooted phone (or a phone with ability to pull/push files from /system partition). Also, you should save a backup of your framework.jar, because your phone might not work well with voice/data SIM cards after this modification. But, if you push original framework.jar back to your phone, everything will be restored.

The modification changes phone status to IN_SERVICE even when it's not connected to the network, so the phone stops searching for networks. Here are [the details](http://www.japanmobiletech.com/2012/03/fix-for-excessive-cell-standby-battery.html), however I don't recommend using batch file and prefer to to all modifications manually, it's safer that way.